# Gatsby site breaks after installing plugins

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, jamstack, gatsby-plugin-feed

I run into a problem when installing gatsby plugins.

My Setup:

```
npm install -g gatsby-cli
gatsby new my-app
gatsby develop
```

When I try to install a plugin from the Gatsby library im getting this error message after installing the plugin:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the bo
> dy of a function component. This could happen for one of the follow
> ing reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (s  uch as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app   See fb.me/react-invalid-hook-call for tips about how to deb  ug and fix
>    this problem.

Is there something wrong with my dep tree?

```
├─┬ gatsby@2.23.10
│ └─┬ gatsby-cli@2.12.50
│   └── react@16.13.1  deduped
└── react@16.13.1
```

Comment: This is not an error due to plugins installation, is because of the usage of the hooks. Can you provide some code to see how are they implemented?

Comment: What code do you want to see? I havent pushed it to Github yet. Basically just done the quick start installation from the Gatsby docs.

Comment: Then show your `gatsby-config.js`. Try removing `node_modules` and `.cache` folder and install your dependencies again.

Comment: @FerranBuireu Can I use: npm install -g gatsby-cli
gatsby new my-app to install the dependencies again?

Comment: `npm install -g gatsby-cli` installs the Gatsby client. You need to remove the `/node_modules` folder inside `my-app` and `.cache`

Comment: @FerranBuireu Okay, Ive removed them now, should I install the gatsby client now again?

Comment: The Gatsby client is global! You have already installed. You only need to remove the dependencies inside your project, not outside. Just remove `/node_modules` and `.cache` folders and run the project again.

Comment: @FerranBuireu so, after deleting /node_modules and .cache , I just have to type gatsby develop?

Comment: That's my guess, yes.

Comment: @FerranBuireu getting this error now: There was a problem loading the local develop command. Gatsby may not be installed in your site's "node_modules" directory. Perhaps you need to run "npm install"? You might need to delete your "package-lock.json" as well.

Comment: @FerranBuireu Its working, thank you!!!

Comment: I've added an answer. I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comments above the solution was:

Removing `node_modules` and `.cache` folder, reinstalling dependencies via `npm install` and `gatsby develop`.